# how to can I list names by countries? node.js, MySql, HANDLEBARS

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

i have this table:
[image]

I want share country name by number of names.
like this:

`USA( 2 names)`
`UK( 1 name)`

how to can I make it?(with handlebars. #each command)

Comment: In mysql this is a basic count grouping by country see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count

Comment: but I want share it with handlebarsjs.(with #each command )

Comment: i'm not familiar with handelbar.js but in general template engines are meant to be used just for displaying data and not for processing it. That means, that you have to deliver your data in a "ready to use" state to the template. So, all the grouping and counting logic needs to be done before that. But if you can assign arrays and append array elements in your templates, this could be done with multiple foreach loops.

Comment: I solved it. of couse with a few mysql comands and new table.